# MyBatis - how to set database properties from swing application?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, mybatis

Let's say I have swing app and I am using mybatis:

```
public class MyAppCView extends FrameView {

    public SqlSession session;
    public StaticMapper mapper;

    public Config c = new Config();

    public MyAppView(SingleFrameApplication app) {
        super(app);      

        String user="root", pswd="root"    

        session = MyBatisSqlSessionFactory.getSqlSessionFactory().openSession();
        mapper = session.getMapper(StaticMapper.class);
```

MyBatisSqlSessionFactory looks like this:

```
public class MyBatisSqlSessionFactory {
    public static Map<String,String> propeties = new HashMap<String,String>();

    protected static final SqlSessionFactory FACTORY;


    static {
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.setProperty("username", user);
            ....

            // how can i get variables from swing application into configuration of sqlfactory?

            Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("wsnscc/mybatis/xml/Configuration.xml");
            FACTORY = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader,props);
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Fatal Error.  Cause: " + e, e);
        }
    }

    public static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory() {
        return FACTORY;
    }
}
```

How can I get variables from swing application into configuration of sqlfactory?

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass the variables into the SQL factory.

You can do this by changing the class `MyBatisSQLSessionFactory` into something like this:

```
public class MyBatisSqlSessionFactory {
    public static Map<String,String> properties = new HashMap<String,String>();

    protected static final SqlSessionFactory FACTORY;

    public MyBatisSqlSessionFactory(String userid, String password) {
        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.setProperty("username", userid);
            props.setProperty("password", password);

            Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader
               ("wsnscc/mybatis/xml/Configuration.xml");

        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Fatal Error.  Cause: " + e, e);
        }
    }

    public static SqlSessionFactory getSqlSessionFactory
            (String userid, String password) 
            throws RuntimeException {
        if (FACTORY == null) 
            FACTORY = new MyBatisSqlSessionFactory(userid, password);
        return FACTORY;
    }
}
```